# Method of moments using just the moments?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

`FindDistributionParameters` (and `EstimatedDistribution`) can use `"MethodOfMoments"` as its `ParameterEstimator`, but as far as I can tell it still requires you to give it the full observed data as its first argument. If I have the moments, but not the full data, is there any way to just pass the observed moments directly to `FindDistributionParameters`? Or do I have to write down the system of equations for the moments myself and then use `FindRoot`?

Comment: You will have to do this yourself but depending on the distribution it shouldn't be difficult. If you need help with a particular example you can always add it to your question.

Comment: Or -- a somewhat roundabout approach -- you could generate lots of data using the parameters you have and then use `FindDistributedParameters` on the data you have generated.

Comment: @bills however if the moments they have are the parameters they wouldn't need to estimate. I think they have a situation where the parameters of interest are some function of the moments

Comment: @AndyRoss That's correct in my case -- if I knew how to generate the data I'd be done! It was just a bit annoying to write it myself, because writing the moments in terms of the parameters involved special functions, and I had to play with the form a bit to avoid over/underflows. I guess that means that I probably wouldn't have been able to use the default `ParameterEstimator` in any case though.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on for Mathematica, called MathStatica, which does exactly what you want, if I understood you right.

Find an example on www.mathstatica.com/examples and click on the left side on the item "Person Fitting."
Ths is an excellent add-on which fits seamless into mma and extends its statistical capabilities.

Best regards
Volker

Comment: I was looking for something that would try to fit an arbitrary parametric form with an arbitrary number of free parameters (matching the number of moments).